# Read and Write from files Java

Tags: java, io

How can i read a number, string or a character from file. I find many ways but i don't know how is the best and clear approach. I want to make input/output operations like the System console.

I created 2 files input.in and output.out and I want to read a number from input.in and and print the number into output.out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("input.in");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        String a = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

I first want to test if is working to read from file but i got this :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
  at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
  at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:9)
```

In the the file input.in i have :

file

i/o

Comment: If you're a beginner, I advise you to avoid the `File` class and stick to using the `Path` class instead wherever possible. Have you checked that your `input.in` file actually contains a line?

Comment: It contains 2 line : first line : file , second one i/o . I put the files into src>default package

Comment: It may not be reading the `input.in` file that you think it's reading. You should give it a full path, or learn about using resources. But for a beginner, try with a full path.

Comment: The path was wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` to do so..

Hope this will serve your purpose

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        Scanner sc = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream("IN File");
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream("OUT File");
            sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println(line);
                byte[] strToBytes = line.getBytes();
                outputStream.write(strToBytes);
                outputStream.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
            }
            // note that Scanner suppresses exceptions
            if (sc.ioException() != null) {
                throw sc.ioException();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            if (sc != null) {
                sc.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like [RealSkeptic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4125191/realskeptic) mentioned in the comments, I suspect your application fails to find the file you have provided. I suggest you adopt the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String filePath = "c:\\absolute\\path\\to\\input.in";
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if(file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Reading contents of file at: " + filePath)
            try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
                while(scanner.hasNext()) {
                    String a = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(a);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("File not found at: " + filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

References:

- [Java File API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html)
- [Java Scanner API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

The path was wrong. For those who also have my problem here is the code for input/output operations:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //the root path is your project name
        File in = new File("input.in");
        File out = new File("output.out");

        Scanner scannerInput = new Scanner(in);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(out));
        String string;
        while(scannerInput.hasNextLine()) {
            string = scannerInput.nextLine();
            writer.write(string);
            writer.newLine();
        }

        writer.flush();//very important
        scannerInput.close();
        writer.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. You may want to improve it to prevent downvotes.